# What is behind JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler)?

Tags: r, sampling, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

I have been using JAGS but I am not quite sure how it actually simulates it values. I need to know in a general sense what's going on in the background.

Answer (score 9):

There are several tools used by JAGS and/or BUGS.

Where conjugate distributions are used, straight [Gibbs sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) is done. When that's not the case, *[adaptive rejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Adaptive_rejection_sampling)*, *[slice sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_sampling)*, or *[Metropolis-Hastings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis-Hastings_algorithm)* might be used (this is the case with BUGS at least; I believe it would be the case for JAGS as well).

You can examine the [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/) yourself and see exactly what it's doing in various circumstances. Also check out the discussion and the wiki.

Martyn Plummer's jags blog also has useful information: http://martynplummer.wordpress.com/

Comment: I followed the links but could find nothing that answered the OP's question.

Comment: @Dominic The OP's question is "what's going on in the background". One of the major statistical tools JAGS uses is mentioned in the first paragraph of my answer (and it's really only the statistical aspect that's on topic). Examining the source code (navigating from the page at the second link to [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/JAGS/3.x/Source/JAGS-3.4.0.tar.gz/download) for the actual 1.6 Mb tarball) which shows *exactly* what's going on. I'm mystified what more you could want, but you're certainly free to post a new question that details what you want to find out.

Comment: I probably misinterpreted the question but I thought the OP was asking about the G for Gibbs in JAGS [otherwise wouldn't it be called JASS - Just Another Slice Sampler :-)] and I am probably being fussy but I think one should have a specification other than the source code. This looks more apposite (to me at any rate): http://puma.isti.cnr.it/dfdownloadnew.php?ident=/cnr.isti/2013-TR-036&langver=en&scelta=NewMetadata.

Comment: Dominic: If you believe you have a better answer, could you post it?

Comment: I accept your challenge :-) but as you say the question is somewhat vague. The question I will answer is why Gibbs sampling works and I will give a few examples using Haskell, JAGS and STAN. Of course without understanding the internals of JAGS which you point out it perfectly possible given enough time, one cannot really say what it is actually doing. In terms of understanding what is going on, I feel one is on firmer ground with STAN as it uses Hamiltonian Monte Carlo. I have a feeling that JAGS knows about conjugate distributions and uses slice sampling if they are not available.

Comment: I ran out of space but I wanted to add that it will take me a few weeks to concoct what I want to say. Indeed one could write a book on the subject :-)

Comment: @Dominic I was just doing some research on this issue this afternoon. You're right that it knows about conjugate distributions and it uses several strategies (of which slice sampling is one) when conjugates are not available. My answer had "one of the strategies" ... which is true, but should be more complete. Your answer would still be very welcome.

Comment: Cool. I shall up vote your answer and eventually provide one of my own.

Comment: Do you mean that slice sampling, Metropolis, etc. might be used within individual Gibbs steps for individual univariate full conditionals that can't be sampled from directly? It isn't totally clear to me from the JAGS code that the iterations of slice sampling etc. are applied separately from one another at the univariate level.

Comment: You can use slice sampling steps or appropriate MH steps among Gibbs steps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the JAGS documentation,

> A report on the samplers chosen by the model, and the stochastic nodes they act on, can be generated using the “SAMPLERS TO” command.

It seems that the user can't control the choice of sampler, which is automatically chosen by JAGS, as described in the [manual](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/4.x/jags_user_manual.pdf). I'd say that typically, it will choose a *slice sampler*. Again, to quote the documentation,

> Slice sampling [Neal, 2003] is the “work horse” sampling method in JAGS.